# Loop wont exit despite being false

Tags: c++, debugging

I know this is a basic question but i cant find a solution for it.
Despite me entering something that makes the loop false, the loop continues.

```
{

        cout << "1 - Load Movie File" << endl;
        cout << "2 - View Total Movie Database Runtime" << endl;
        cout << "3 - View Movies by Rating" << endl;
        cout << "4 - Export Movies by Genre" << endl;
        cout << "5 - Clear Currently Loaded Database" << endl;
        cout << "6 - Print Database Sorted by Year" << endl;
        cout << "Q - Quit" << endl;
        cout << "Selection >> ";

        do{
                cin >> selectionMenu;
                selectionMenu = tolower(selectionMenu);

                if(selectionMenu != '1' || selectionMenu != '2' || selectionMenu != '3' || selectionMenu != '4' || selectionMenu != '5' || selectionMenu != '6' || selectionMenu != 'q' )
                {

                        cout << "Please enter a valid selection: ";

                }

        }while(selectionMenu != 1 || selectionMenu != 2 || selectionMenu != 3 || selectionMenu != 4 || selectionMenu != 5 || selectionMenu != 6 || selectionMenu != 'q' );



}
```

the selectionMenu variable is a character in case anyone asks

Comment: You want `&&`, not `||`. `selectionMenu != 1 || selectionMenu != 2` for example is always true.

Comment: You also want to compare to *either* int or char. Your `if()` compares to char and your loop does something quite different.

Comment: The takeaway here is don't assume what the value of something is. A loop will always exit if its condition is false. If it didn't exit, the condition wasn't false.

Comment: `selectionMenu` can't be all 7 values at the same time.

Comment: IMHO, the `switch` statement is better at handling menu selections than an `if-else-if` ladder.  You can use the `default` case for handling invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

This condition:

```
if(selectionMenu != '1' || selectionMenu != '2' || selectionMenu != '3' || selectionMenu != '4' || selectionMenu != '5' || selectionMenu != '6' || selectionMenu != 'q' )
```

is guaranteed to always be true. Use `&&` instead of `||`.